# Flash IDE, Haxe & OpenFL - Invalid Data Swf Error #2136

Tags: flash, flashdevelop, haxe, 2d-games, openfl

We've recently run into a show stopping issue and can't seem to find any one else on the net who has the same problem (although there have been similar ones).

We're currently developing a game using Haxe and OpenFL. We use FlashDevelop to code the game and the official FlashIDE (CS6) to create UI/menus which is then hooked up via code in FlashDevelop. A few weeks ago the FlashIDE crashed while the FLA was being worked on. Nothing appeared to be wrong as the file opened normally, however, after building our game in FlashDevelop we received the following message "Invalid Data Swf Error #2136". Since then we've done a handful of things that will seem to fix it temporarily, but as of now, none of those solutions work. At this point we think its some sort of flash limit or an issue with OpenFL, Haxe, and FlashIDE (or some combination of).

I'd like to note that we've noticed some weird behavior - if we removed any clip the error disappears and if we add it back, the error returns.

Here's what we've tried:

- recreating movie clips that were created after the crash
- converting the FLA into a archive and repairing it with WinRAR
- splitting the FLA into two files
- copying the library into a new FLA file

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Compile it to swf and disassemble, then you can find exact place where format is wrong. (The disassemble part could be done easily with haxe since it already have all the libs for that.)

I'm not sure, but it should be possible to reclaim everything from swf to fla after it will be fixed, so you can fix all errors from code.

If it is not possible to reclaim, then you can just recreate entities you will find misformatted.

Comment: How exactly do we do that? We've been told to "fix" the uncompressed/XML but we have no idea to recognize what's actually corrupted.

Comment: Um... As I said earlier, by parsing the resulting swf and finding the exact place format is wrong.

Comment: I think I might be a bit confused. I'm assuming saving out the FLA as an XFL and examining the XML data would have the same effect. The problem is that XML data is valid, but if any data is corrupt within the XML, it is unknown to me.

Comment: Can you show me the example of the "wrong format" so that I know what I'm looking for? Because there is no clear indication of what a corrupt symbol/shape looks like.

Comment: There could be hundreds of options I guess. just use format library. format.swf package is your starting point, throw in others as yuo descend by tree to actual data when needed. However, chances are just format.swf will be enough. It will throw exception when it parse incorrectly formatted data.

Comment: How exactly do I use the format.swf package to parse the swf?

Comment: To be honest, it's getting ridiculous. This package Reader class have just a few methods. It actually takes longer to type this answer than to look at the class and figure out which method you need to use. So I suggest you to do exactly that.